# regexp in ansible for replacing 'localhost'

Tags: regex, ansible

I am using the replace module in ansible to replace a line in my file

original line is `#listen_addresses = 'localhost'`

I want to replace it to the following `listen_addresses = '*'`

This my playbook entry

```
replace: path=/usr/pgsql-9.6/data/postgresql.conf regexp='#listen_addresses(\s)*=\'locahost'\' replace='listen_addresses = *' remote_src=yes backup=yes
```

The above playbook is unable to make the substituion. Pls guide me with the actual regexp

Comment: explain what you mean by "Doesn't seem to work." Edit the question and give the result you have

Comment: @baptistemm The playbook which i have pasted is unable to make the substitution. Can u help me with the proper regexp which i have to use.

Comment: @achak01 You don’t seem to allow for the space after the `=`.

Comment: @achack01 learn to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the full line to replace it, just match the beginning of the line (using `^`) the text plus a greedy matching (`.*`)

```
  tasks:
  - replace: 
      path: /usr/pgsql-9.6/data/postgresql.conf
      regexp: '^#listen_addresses.*'
      replace: 'listen_addresses = *'
      remote_src: yes
      backup: yes
```

I suggest also to reformat the code this way (mind `=` were replaced by `:`) this is more readable

Comment: This will also replace an option called `listen_adresses_foobar`. Use [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for identifiers: `\b`.